# Pumas are large, cat-like animals which are found in America. Why not use ‘were’ instead of the second ‘are’?

Tags: grammar

Pumas are large, cat-like animals which are found in America.

Why not use ‘were’ instead of the second ‘are’?

Comment: The second **are** indicates that they are still found in America (pumas in South America, cougars in North America)

Comment: Because they still *are* found in America.

Answer (score 1):

> Pumas are large, cat-like animals which are found in America.

The Puma is a large animal and is still present in America.

> Pumas are large, cat-like animals which were found in America.

The Puma is a large animal but it is no longer present in America (because it went extinct, for example).